# Why not use global optimization algorithms like PSO to solve decentralized control problems?

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, global-optimization

I do not see many works that use global optimization algorithms to solve decentralized control problems. Here the decentralized control problem means some entries of the feedback matrix are constrained to be zero (in the closed-loop state-space model).

Could anyone give me a reason?

a). It is difficult to apply global optimization algorithms to solve decentralized control problems.

b). It just lacks significance to do such research.

c). There are some successful applications, but you don't find them.

Comment: Re: using global optimization algorithms, PSO is not the state of the art: CMA-ES and its variants cover most of that frontier. While not decentralized, an example of Bayesian global optimization for control is at https://github.com/uber-research/TuRBO